# Workaround to saving a model with many properties without using too much CPU time?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a model with a lot of properties and when I try to write it I get a warning on the logs that the request is taking too much CPU times (over 1000cpu_ms and over 8000api_cpu_ms).

The following test program demonstrates the issue:

```
class TestModel(db.Model): 
    user = db.UserProperty() 
    p1 = db.StringProperty() 
    p2 = db.StringProperty() 
    p3 = db.StringProperty()
    p4 = db.StringProperty()
    p5 = db.StringProperty() # 475cpu_ms with 1..5 only
    p6 = db.StringProperty()
    p7 = db.StringProperty()
    p8 = db.StringProperty()
    p9 = db.StringProperty()
    p10 = db.StringProperty() # 760cpu_ms with 1..10 only
    p11 = db.StringProperty()
    p12 = db.StringProperty()
    p13 = db.ListProperty(unicode)
    p14 = db.ListProperty(int) 
    p15 = db.ListProperty(int)
    p16 = db.BooleanProperty()
    p17 = db.DateTimeProperty() #over 1000cpu_ms with all these


class DebugitHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        instance = TestModel()
        instance = instance.put() 
        self.response.out.write("Done.")
```

All the CPU time is spent on that one `.put()` call.

Other than splitting the model into more than one (which, probably won't help as I would still have the same number of properties) is there a way to get around this problem? a way to put 1 instance with 20 properties in the datastore without taking over 1 second of CPU time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [quota documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html):

> As the number of properties associated with a given entity increases,
>   so does the CPU time required to read and write that entity

If you don't need to sort or filter on each of these properties, you could add the `indexed = False` declaration to some of them; this should save some CPU time..

```
class TestModel(db.Model): 
    user = db.UserProperty(indexed = False) 
    p1 = db.StringProperty(indexed = False) 
    p2 = db.StringProperty(indexed = False) 
    p3 = db.StringProperty(indexed = False)
    ....
```